# How to load a pretrained model after training it?

Tags: pytorch, kaggle

I have trained a model for caption generation , I've used VIT as an encoder and GPT2 as a decoder. After training, these files were saved: model.pth and image-caption-generator checkpoint-4045 : config.json, generation_config.json, model.safetensors, optimizer.pt, preprocessor_config.json, rng_state.pth, scheduler.pt, trainer_state.json, training_args.bin

I've saved the outputs to my computer then opened the notebook and upload them but I didn't know how to load them again to make predictions

Comment: `model = torch.load('model.pth')` — read tutorials or something - https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/saveloadrun_tutorial.html